# FreePascal beginners issue

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I need to port some code from FreePascal to C. I'm a professional C developer but know nothing of Pascal. Most of the code can be ported quite easily but one line is giving me a headache. What exactly is this supposed to do:

```
New(newBack); 
curBackPtr^ := newBack; 
curBackPtr := @(newBack^.next);
```

What is confusing me here is the fact that `newBack` is assigned to `curBackPtr` and right after that `newBack.next` is assigned to `curBackPtr` without `curBackPtr` ever being accessed. Isn't the first assignment superfluous then and can be safely removed? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Does it help to know that `foo^` is like `*foo` in C, and `@(foo)` is like `&foo` in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Comment: You've got too much time on your hands - LOL. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
New(newBack);
```

Allocates memory for a newBack type and stores the pointer in newBack.

> curBackPtr^ := newBack;

Assigns the newBack pointer to what curBackPtr points to.

> curBackPtr := @(newBack^.next);

Assigns curBackPtr to point to newBack^.next, that is, to the next pointer itself, not to what it points to.